# In Custom Configuration Sections, can you make a ConfigurationProperty required if another ConfigurationProperty is set to a certain value?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, app-config

I would like to try and enforce a configuration property's existence if another configuration property exists that is set to a certain value.

For example, if this is my [Custom Configuration Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
<CustomSettingsSection>
  <Action ActionType="SendEmail" FromAddress="SomeEmailAddress"/>
  <Action ActionType="LogToFile"/>
</CustomSettingsSection>
```

I would like to make it so that the user must always specify a FromAddress whenever the ActionType is set to SendEmail, otherwise I do not require they specify the FromAddress, as not specifying the FromAddress on an ActionType of LogToFile is logically unnecessary.